# Conversão de CEP para coordenadas geográficas usando python

Tags: python

Fala pessoal, estou com um erro no código a seguir que peguei em partes de várias publicações aqui do site.
[Erro01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNefe.png)

Estou utilizando python e biblioteca dos correios (pycep_correios) junto a de georreferenciamento do Geocoders.
Na primeira tentativa, sem os exceptions, me retornava erro de não localização dos CEPs ou CEP invalido.
Após adicionar os exceptions, o erro informado não ocorre mais porém passou a ocorrer o erro da imagem em anexo e a seguir.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File F:\Gerados\CEP-LatLong.py:64 in <module>
    latitude, longitude = extrai_lat_long(cep)

  File F:\Gerados\CEP-LatLong.py:51 in extrai_lat_long
    location = geolocator.geocode(endereco['logradouro'] + ", " + endereco['cidade'] + " - " + endereco['bairro'])

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'endereco' referenced before assignment
```

Aqui a base resumida de CEP's que utilizei (a base original possui cerca de 1500 CEP's)

```
  CEP
36092235
36107000
36010904
36092245
36010900
36001970
36081000
36092005
36010906
```

Além de que em muitos casos não me retorna coordenadas validas mesmo constando no site ceps.io, em comparativo com o georreferenciamento feito pelo Google Earth, este API me retorna mais valores nulos. Pela experiência é isso mesmo ou falta algo no processamento?

Abaixo está o code que estou utilizando para o processamento da base de dados:

```
import csv
import pycep_correios
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim


lista_ceps = []   
with open('CEP-faltante.csv') as file:
    next(file)  # Pula o cabeçalho, caso exista
    for row in csv.reader(file):
        lista_ceps.append(row[0])


def extrai_lat_long(cep):
    
    from pycep_correios import exceptions, WebService
    
    try:
    
        endereco = pycep_correios.get_address_from_cep(cep, webservice=WebService.VIACEP)
    
    
    except exceptions.InvalidCEP as eic:
        print(eic)
    
    except exceptions.CEPNotFound as ecnf:
        print(ecnf)
    
    except exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print(errc)
    
    except exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print(errt)
    
    except exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print(errh)
    
    except exceptions.BaseException as e:
        print(e)

    
    
    
    geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent="test_app")
    location = geolocator.geocode(endereco['logradouro'] + ", " + endereco['cidade'] + " - " + endereco['bairro'])
             
    if location:
        return location.latitude, location.longitude
    return '0', '0'


with open('ceps_lat_long2.csv', 'w') as file:
     cabecalho = ['cep', 'latitude', 'longitude']
     writer = csv.DictWriter(file, fieldnames=cabecalho)

     writer.writeheader() # Escreve o cabeçalho
     for cep in lista_ceps:
         latitude, longitude = extrai_lat_long(cep)
         writer.writerow({'cep': cep, 'latitude': latitude, 'longitude': longitude})
```

Então a ajuda que preciso é como resolver essa quebra no código, pois ele salva um csv porém até a linha do erro de CEP, ou se daria para pular esses valores

Comment: Você [já fez essa pegunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/564027/70), ela foi fechada e explicações foram dadas de como fazer para melhorar e reabrir. Não tem muita eficácia postar a mesma coisa com os mesmos problemas. Você pode restaurar sua publicação original e editar como explicado lá, aí a postagem  é reanalisada e pode ser reaberta. Para evitar duplicação de orientações e desencontro de informações, o campo de comentários aqui está desativado, mas em restaurando a original, o espaço de lá pode ser usado (até para que a comunidade possa dar dicas ou ajudar mesmo com a pergunta fechada).